# Kotlin Multiplatform project gives this error while trying to access StateFlow Cannot access kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kmm

In my KMM App trying to collect the state of the data via coroutine `StateFlow` but it throwing me this error does anyone know what could cause this to happen

> Cannot access 'kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow' which is a supertype of 'kotlinx.coroutines.flow.StateFlow'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies

```
var response = viewModel.events.authenticateUser(User(username = "",password = ""))
print(viewModel.stateFlow.value) // When it tries the .value it throws this error
```

Here is my gradle file

```
    plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("com.android.library")
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.4.31"
}

kotlin {
    val ktorVersion = "1.4.0"
    val serializationVersion = "1.0.0-RC"
    val coroutinesVersion = "1.4.3-native-mt"
    android()
    ios {
        binaries {
            framework {
                baseName = "shared"
            }
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-core:$serializationVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutinesVersion")
            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-common"))
                implementation(kotlin("test-annotations-common"))
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1")
                implementation("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0")
                implementation("com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-android:$ktorVersion")
            }
        }
        val androidTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-junit"))
                implementation("junit:junit:4.13")
            }
        }
        val iosMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-ios:$ktorVersion")
            }
        }
        val iosTest by getting
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion(29)
    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion(24)
        targetSdkVersion(29)
    }
}

val packForXcode by tasks.creating(Sync::class) {
    group = "build"
    val mode = System.getenv("CONFIGURATION") ?: "DEBUG"
    val sdkName = System.getenv("SDK_NAME") ?: "iphonesimulator"
    val targetName = "ios" + if (sdkName.startsWith("iphoneos")) "Arm64" else "X64"
    val framework =
        kotlin.targets.getByName<KotlinNativeTarget>(targetName).binaries.getFramework(mode)
    inputs.property("mode", mode)
    dependsOn(framework.linkTask)
    val targetDir = File(buildDir, "xcode-frameworks")
    from({ framework.outputDirectory })
    into(targetDir)
}

tasks.getByName("build").dependsOn(packForXcode)
```

Comment: Is it a compilation error or just an IDE error? [There are](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-31052) a number of issue regarding the wrong IDE error.

Comment: @esentsov it's strange seems sounds like an IDE error to me it mixes up dependencies it seems :(

Comment: Invalidate cache and restart didn't help too (Tried cleaning up build folders and .gradle folders manually still the same